# MotionLayout animation not working when DataBinding is used

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding, android-motionlayout

So I'm using dataBinding and MVVM for my app which means I use the DataBindingUtil class instead of SetContentView like:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_record)
```

In my layout file, I used motion layout (used as the root layout) to animate a CalendarView widget to transition up to the bottom of the screen.

```
        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/datePickerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#191919"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/CalendarViewTheme"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

And in my End constraint, I have the following code:

```
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/datePickerView">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
        </Constraint>
```

Inside my activity when I call `ml.transitionToEnd()`, the calendarView should animate from the under of the screen (not visible on the screen) to bottom of the screen (entire view visible on the screen at the bottom). This animation happens when I use `setContentView()` but not when I use dataBinding ie. `val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`

In a much simpler way to put it, how do I get MotionLayout to work from my activity when I'm using DataBinding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Kotlin, but in Java I handle it this way:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
```

This works well with MotionLayout.

Comment: I basically did the same thing but in Kotlin. And everything else works fine except for motion layout. The animations don’t work when I use the DataBindingUtil class.

Comment: @PraantoSamadder but you saw that I used `.inflate()`and not `.setContentView()` ? Or is this the Kotlin equivalent?

Comment: This is an Activity not a Fragment. I did use ``.inflate()`` in fragments when using DataBinding with Kotlin.